# getting lat_lng error while using google places api

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API with Python to build a chatbot application to suggest nearby places.

I am referring to the below link:
https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places

I am doing something like this:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

API_KEY = ''

google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
location='Mumbai', keyword='Restaurants',
radius=1000, types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT])

if query_result.has_attributions:
    print query_result.html_attributions


for place in query_result.places:
    print place.name
    print place.geo_location
    print place.place_id
```

Its given in the link itself. However , I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "run.py", line 9, in <module>
radius=1000, types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT])
 File "/home/neetu/Desktop/python-google-places/googleplaces/__init__.py",           line 281, in nearby_search
lat_lng_str = self._generate_lat_lng_string(lat_lng, location)
 File "/home/neetu/Desktop/python-google-places/googleplaces/__init__.py",   line 593, in _generate_lat_lng_string
'lat_lng must be a dict with the keys, \'lat\' and \'lng\'. Cause: %s' %   str(e))
ValueError: lat_lng must be a dict with the keys, 'lat' and 'lng'. Cause:   Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI&address=Mumbai failed with  response code: REQUEST_DENIED
```

Any help is super welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:
[https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/blob/master/googleplaces/**init**.py](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/blob/master/googleplaces/__init__.py):

You should be able to provide a location instead of a lat_lng pair, but you could try giving a lat_lng instead of a location.

Try removing:

```
location="Mumbai"
```

and adding

```
lat_lng={'lat:19.148320, 'lng':72.888794}
```

After digging through the code, I understand the error.
The error you got was:

> ValueError: lat_lng must be a dict with the keys, 'lat' and 'lng'. Cause:   >Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?>sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI&address=Mumbai failed >with  response code: REQUEST_DENIED

what it is saying is that it tried to look to google to get the lat_lng pair for "Mumbai", but the request failed as it was denied.  Use a valid API key from Google and it should work.

Comment: thanks a lot ! you just saved me :) but how did you get the lat_lng value for 'mumbai'?

Comment: I just googled "Mumbai" and right clicked a location near the center of the city on google maps, and clicked "whats here?" the lat lng is at the bottom.